# Difference between Account Extended Private Key and BIP32 Extended Private Key

Tags: wallets, accounts, private-key, keymanagement

I was using this [this useful tool](https://iancoleman.io/bip39/) to verify that my wallet generation process was accurate, however when I thought I was generating an Account Extended Private Key, I realized I was actually generating a BIP32 Extended Private Key.

What is the difference? Can I derive an Account Extended Private Key from a BIP32 Extended Private Key or have I done something wrong?

EDIT: I see on the page there's a small explanation next to each field.

**Account Extended Private Key:** The account extended keys can be used for importing to most BIP44 compatible wallets, such as mycelium or electrum.

**BIP32 Extended Private Key:** The BIP32 derivation path and extended keys are the basis for the derived addresses.

Can I have a more detailed explanation for the differences on how to derive these?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Forgot about this question until I saw some people up voting it. Now I know the answer so I'll share the differences between these two types of private keys.

**Account Extended Private Key:** This represents the extended private key derived with the BIP 44 derivation path `m / purpose' / coin_type' / account' / chain / address_index`

**BIP32 Extended Private Key:** This represents the extended private key derived from the derivation path `m/0'/0'/k'` with `k` being the extended private key.

For more reading on HD Wallets (BIP44) take a look at [Harsha Goli's article on HD Wallets](https://medium.com/bitcraft/hd-wallets-explained-from-high-level-to-nuts-and-bolts-9a41545f5b0)

For all intents and purposes BIP32 derivation paths are not used and were deprecated by BIP44.

The mistake I made was by deriving the key for BIP44 a level too low.